# Google Bigtable is concept of multi-tenant database or not?

Tags: multi-tenant

I don't know what is true or not. Can you advise me?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines multitenancy as:

> Multitenancy refers to a principle in software architecture where a single instance of the software runs on a software-as-a-service (SaaS) vendor's servers, serving multiple client organizations (tenants).

So, the question becomes does google run an single instance of bigtable, or an individual one for each client on their app servers? To be honest there's no real way of knowing. A single instance scenario could isolate clients so it appears as if they have their own individual version running, conversely you couldn't tell if you have your own individual server running either - google hasn't released enough information either way.

It's unlikely that every google apps customer gets their own instance to connect to, but unless google makes a statement either way, it's all just guesswork.